# Execution of next task in case of failure- airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

1.4 with composer 2.0.

I have a DAG that runs multiple tasks, the problem I have is that when one task fails, it runs the next one anyway.

According to the airflow documentation this should not be the case, but rather terminate the execution of the DAG after the task fails.
Tasks are dependent, so if one fails, the next will fail.
I want that in case a task fails, the execution of the DAG will be terminated.

[image]

```
default_args = {
    'owner': owner,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 28 ,15 ,0 ,0 ), #2021-08-08 10:00:00 UTC-0
    'email': email,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 0,  # Retry once before failing the task.
    #'on_failure_callback': incident_pg, #ejecuta funcion en caso de que la tarea falle 
}
with DAG(dag_id=inst_dag_id,
                default_args = default_args,
                catchup = True,  
                max_active_runs = 5,
                #schedule_interval = None) as dag: #ejecucion manual
                schedule_interval = "0 15 * * *" ) as dag:
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is with task definition. It would be more transparent to have the task code in your question. From what you have in the question, there is no '`trigger_rule`' parameter defined and from apache-airflow's definition of BaseOperator, the `trigger_rule` by default is `all_success` which means that all the upstream tasks are to be successful before downstream tasks can execute.

Check if you have the trigger rule on the task `delete_bq_table` as `all_done` if so, remove that or change it to `all_success`